# MySQL Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint - repeating error

Tags: mysql

When I try to forward engineer my new schema, I am getting the error

> Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint.

My foreign key column is indexed and the data type of this column and the referenced column in parent table are exactly same. Also I am using InnoDB as well. Even then I am keep on getting the error. I have referred so many links in StackOverflow and nothing worked out in my case. What could have been unnoticed apart from the above things?

```
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Employee_Management`.`Employee`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Employee_Management`.`Employee` (
  `idEmployee` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `dateOfBirth` DATE NOT NULL,
  `dateOfJoining` DATE NOT NULL,
  `designation` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL,
  `clBalance` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  `elBalance` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  `slBalance` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  `gender` CHAR NOT NULL,
  `role` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `authRole` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idEmployee`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Employee_Management`.`Domain`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Employee_Management`.`Domain` (
  `idDomain` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `domainHead` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idDomain`),
  INDEX `fk_DomainHead_idx` (`domainHead` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_DomainHead`
    FOREIGN KEY (`domainHead`)
    REFERENCES `Employee_Management`.`Employee` (`idEmployee`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

> Error: could not create foreign key constraint.

But the date type of domainHead in Domain table and idEmployee in Employee table are same and both are using InnoDB. Even then the error is repeating.

Comment: Works for me. Can you refine your example so the error reproduces?

Comment: Nice... But actually the database contains so many tables and i have posted only the part showing error. Also in the Employee table itself half of the columns are not at all generated. Something weired...

Comment: Make sure you don't have the same constraint name `fk_DomainHead` in multiple tables. Constraint names have to be unique across the entire database.

Comment: No. I am not using that constraint name anywhere except that place in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was with the MySQL Workbench that I have used. The application was not compatible with my system with Ubuntu 15.04. Afterwards I have successfully created the same database through terminal.